# Is it possible to reference an object, i.e. table, within a separate table in R?

Tags: r

I have a R script that generates a table containing days and distances for an individual animal:

i.e.

```r
bill_distance_table =  

|day|distance| date       |  

| 1 | 100    | 04-10-2018 |  
| 2 | 150    | 04-11-2018 |  
| 3 | 125    | 04-12-2018 |
```

Now, I would like to run this script on a whole group of animals, and save the resulting tables to another table or data frame. Then, say I want to access 'animal X' distance table, I could just reference that row in the final table to return the distance table:

i.e.

```r
global_table:  

|animal|  name    | table_reference     |  

| 1    |   bill   | bill_distance_table |  
| 2    |   joe    | joe_distance_table  |  
| 3    |   sue    | sue_distance_table  |  

global_table[1,3] 

(would return)

|day|distance| date       |  

| 1 | 100    | 04-10-2018 |  
| 2 | 150    | 04-11-2018 |  
| 3 | 125    | 04-12-2018 |
```

I would like to know, is this possible with R? To nest tables within tables?

Or, would it be easier to create a list of tables, and just reference save reference keys within the global table?

Thanks!

HH

I am new to R and unsure of its potential in terms of Object's..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the tidyr package, but the data should already be in one dataframe, e.g.:

```r
# Give each a dataframe a column with the appropriate name.
bill_dist$animal <- "bill"
joe_dist$animal <- "joe"
sue_dist$animal <- "sue"

# Bind dataframes together.
dist_df <- rbind(bill_dist, joe_dist, sue_dist)

dist_df

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 9 x 4
    day  dist date       animal
  <int> <dbl> <date>     <chr> 
1     1   100 2018-10-04 bill  
2     2   150 2018-11-04 bill  
3     3   125 2018-12-04 bill  
4     1   130 2018-10-04 joe   
5     2   110 2018-11-04 joe   
6     3    90 2018-12-04 joe   
7     1   160 2018-10-04 sue   
8     2   155 2018-11-04 sue   
9     3   140 2018-12-04 sue
```

This type of "long" dataframe is probably more useful than a nested dataframe, i.e. it is easier to manipulate for analysis, so consider just sticking with this. That said, once you have this dataframe you can run the following to get a nested dataframe:

```r
library(tidyr)

nested_dist_df <- nest(dist_df, -animal)

nested_dist_df

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  animal data            
  <chr>  <list>          
1 bill   <tibble [3 × 3]>
2 joe    <tibble [3 × 3]>
3 sue    <tibble [3 × 3]>
```

You can now access the individual dataframes using `[[` syntax:

```r
nested_dist_df[[1, 2]]

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    day  dist date      
  <int> <dbl> <date>    
1     1   100 2018-10-04
2     2   150 2018-11-04
3     3   125 2018-12-04
```